# Does synthetic division and long division of polynomials always give the same remainder?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Does synthetic division and long division of polynomials always give the same remainder? On a couple of the problems I did, I did, but now I've got a couple that are coming out different and I don't know if I'm doing them wrong or...

Comment: Theoretical yes, students solving no.

Comment: Crap. And I thought I finally had it too. Oh well. Back to square one. Nice way of answering by the way, lol.

Comment: If you provide us with an example of a problem in which you obtained different answers using the two methods, we could tell you the source of your error.  Note, for instance, that while you can always use long division that synthetic division can only be applied to divisors of the form $x - k$.